# How to specify the display manager of a new session launched from tty?

Tags: window-manager, graphics, i3, display-manager, startx

When prompting startx from tty, the graphical display start but without any display manager but have a `xterm` from which my display manager have to be launched.

How can I directly launch a session with a given display manager from tty1 (i3wm for instance).

Comment: A display manager is a program that shows a login prompt. That doesn't seem to be what you mean. Did you mean *window manager*? i3 is a window manager.

Answer (score 1):

You can start a display manager by using a .xinitrc file in your home directory, which is executed when you start X11. For example, the last line in my .xinitrc is

```
exec xmonad
```

Feel free to replace xmonad with, e.g., i3wm.

Comment: The post already exists on se. I used `xinit session -- :1 -xf86config config.con`